# Is it possible to load an external SVG fill into an inline-svg element?

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to create an inline-svg text element with a `fill` attribute loading a gradient defined in an external svg document.

#### Inline SVG

```
<svg>
    <text fill="url(/path/to/svg.svg#gradient)">Mask this text</text>
</svg>
```

#### /path/to/svg.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#ffeab4; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color:#ed9f3b; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:#ed9f3b; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="70%" style="stop-color:#ffeab4; stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#ed9f3b; stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/jsRrE/) and here is a [gist of the SVG gradient](https://gist.github.com/potench/5146989#file-gradient-svg) I'm trying to load.

#### Question

- Is it possible to load an external `fill` into an inline-svg element?
- Have I just defined my external gradient incorrectly or am referencing it incorrectly?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/potench/5146989/raw/681b28133c20fe491acaf7d871195d2bd2f02569/gradient.svg#gradient content-disposition: attachment; filename=gradient.svg I suspect this may well interfere with the file being used as an external source.

Comment: I've also saved the external file here for testing: http://potench.com/gradient.svg Will update the jsfiddle.

Comment: That's being served with a mime type of text/plain so that definitely won't work unless you fix it.

Comment: Hmm, it works in Chrome anyways... http://jsfiddle.net/jsRrE/3/

Comment: That fiddle isn't using the text/plain mime type file.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work - I believe it's picking up the `#gradient` from the second `<svg>` block. Changing it to `id="gradient2"` breaks the first `<svg>` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using external fill and stroke is allowed by the SVG spec, but not all browsers implement that part. Opera and Firefox does, but not Chrome for example.

A live example [here](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/usingExternalGradient.svg).

The syntax you describe is correct. E.g `fill="url(example.svg#gradient)"` will fetch the external example.svg and use the specified gradient from that file.

Comment: wow this sux, is this still the case in chrome? I'm trying to have the same <def> > gradient effect on multiple inline SVG's using fill: url(/assets/def.svg#grad), is there no crossbrowser way to do this?